# how to extract the images from string using javascript regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract images from string like below:
l

```js
let str = 'any words abc sdf sdf http://test/files/1/1574322005738295297/2222681.jpeghttp://test/files/1/2040655876098/Image131607.png';
```

I need to get the img urls like:

```js
const expectedImgList = ['http://test/files/1/1574322005738295297/2222681.jpeg','http://test/files/1/2040655876098/Image131607.png'];
```

How can i achieve that with javascript Regexp?

Answer (score 1):

I have made the assumptions that

a. all files are accessed using http://, not https://

b. the concatenation of two images without a space between them in your example was deliberate.

c all image paths are followed by another image path or a space char.

Based on these I offer the following code that uses a modified version of your sample str:

```js
let str = 'any words abc sdf http://test/y.jpg sdf http://test/2222681.jpeghttp://test/Image131607.png http://test/x.jpg';
let link="";
let regex = /\bhttp:\/\/[^ ]*/g;
let found = str.match(regex);
let result = [];
let r = 0,f1,f=0;
while (f<found.length) {
    let found_inner = found[f].split('http://');
    result[r++] = "http://"+found_inner[1];
    fi=2;
    while (fi<found_inner.length) {
        link = "http://"+found_inner[fi];
        result.splice(r++, 0,link);
        fi++;
    }
    f++;
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi! I made the code runnable in stackoverflow. Use the `<>` button to create runnable snippets here. This preserves your answer even if jsfiddle might not exist in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple URLs concatenated without space. Here is a solution that assumes that a split should happen between a word character (which is the last char of the previous URL, and the beginning of the next URL `http://`:

```js
const str = 'any words abc sdf sdf http://test/files/1/1574322005738295297/2222681.jpeghttp://test/files/1/2040655876098/Image131607.png';
const regex1 = /(\w)(?=https?:\/\/)/g;
const regex2 = /[ "']/;
const regex3 = /^https?:\/\//;
let result = str
  .replace(regex1, '$1 ') // add space between URLs
  .split(regex2)          // split on space and quotes (in case of URL in HTML)
  .filter(s => regex3.test(s)); // keep only URLs
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
[
  "http://test/files/1/1574322005738295297/2222681.jpeg",
  "http://test/files/1/2040655876098/Image131607.png"
]
```

Explanation of regex1:

- `(\w)` -- capture group 1: one word char
- `(?=https?:\/\/)` -- positive lookahead for `http://` or `https://`
- `g` flag: gloabl, e.g. replace multiple times

Explanation of regex2:

- `[ "']` -- one of  , `"`, or `'`

Explanation of regex3:

- `^https?:\/\/` -- literal `http://` or `https://` at the begiining of the string